# Deploy Notebook VM via ARM Template?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

Is it possible to deploy an AML Notebook VM via an ARM template? If so, is there an example or documentation somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not supported today, but ARM support is in our roadmap